# IOS TableView selecting row crashes application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having problem with my iphone twiiter app. That when i select a row in table view my application gets crashed and shows " Thread 1: Program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" ."

Here is the code for My table view

```
//
//  PersonListViewController.m
//  AssignmentPresenceII
//
//  Created by Waqas Naseem on 8/7/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PersonListViewController.h"


@implementation PersonListViewController

@synthesize users;
//@synthesize person;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

       self.title=@"People";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

    NSString *filePath=[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TwitterUsers.plist"];

    self.users=[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    //users=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Waqas",@"RAmiz",@"Afnan", nil];

    for(NSString *s in users)
    {
        //NSLog(@"Name : %@",s);
    }

    //NSArray *array=
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    users=nil;
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.users release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.users count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellId=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId] autorelease];
    }
    //NSString *nameString=[self.users objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


   // NSDictionary *dic=[TwitterHelper fetchInfoForUsername:nameString];


   // NSString *displayName=[dic objectForKey:@"name"];


    //NSLog(@"Name is %@:",displayName);


    //NSString *picURL=[dic objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];

   // NSArray *userTimeLine=[TwitterHelper fetchTimelineForUsername:nameString];

   // person=[[Person alloc] initWithUserName:nameString displayName:displayName imgURL:picURL statuses:userTimeLine];



    //cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]]];




    //[dic release];

    //cell.textLabel.text=nameString;

    cell.textLabel.text=@"Hello";



    return  cell;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations


    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);



}




-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
}



@end
```

Comment: enable zombie objects and check

Comment: enable NSZombie objects and make a breakpoint in didSelect function and check at which line you program is getting crashed

Comment: How do you enable NSZombie objects?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you've commented out most of the code, the table appears (with a bunch of "Hello" values), but if you click on it, it will crash. If that's indeed the case, it sounds like you have your data source defined, but your delegate is not. Check the data source and delegate settings in Interface Builder.

Comment: In Xcode, next to the "Run" and "Stop" buttons, there is a drop down with your "Schemes". Click on that (on the left side by the scheme name, not by the device/simulator name on the right), and choose "Edit Scheme". You'll see enable zombies there. This is a good thing to have turned while debugging (especially if you're not using ARC), but I'm not confident that a dangling pointer is the problem here. Still, not a bad option to keep on while debugging, though.